# Error de sonido en ubuntu 16, salida para torpes

Tags: ubuntu

Hace dos días mi audio estaba bien, al día de hoy encendí la maquina y no tenia sonido y en la configuración de audio decía **salida para torpes**

ya desinstale e instale pulse-audio y alsa-audio pero sigo sin tener sonido.

¿Alguien que me pueda orientar donde esta el problema del audio?

Comment: Cuando me insulta Linux, no sé por qué en lugar de enojarme, me saca una sonrisa. Incluso cuando la sección de `insults` está activada.

Answer (score 4):

Prueba con estos comandos:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa; sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse*; rm -r ~/.pulse*; sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`
```

Reinicias y con esto debería solucionarse; al menos en teoría, porque a mi no me funcionó en primera instancia.

Lo que hice después fue instalar la última versión del kernel de ubuntu 16.04 (creo que esto es opcional, lo hice más que nada por si algo se daño o corrompió con todo lo que probé). Utilicé el siguiente comando:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

Es de la [wiki oficial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) de ubuntu.

Luego seguí los pasos que se detallan en [esta respuesta de askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914463/dummy-output-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04), que la traduzco, primero ejecutas estos comandos:

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

Luego:

```
pacmd list-cards
```

Si esto te muestra las tarjetas de audio disponibles eso sería todo, sino verifica que el sistema las encuentra con el siguiente comando:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
```

Si esto te devuelve resultados y ves listadas las tarjetas de audio, realiza los siguientes pasos:

1. Reinicia la máquina e ingresa a la bios
2. Dentro de las configuraciones de la bios deshabilita el controlador de audio.
3. Guarda los cambios e inicia sesión en ubuntu, si te fijas pulseaudio ya lista las tarjetas de sonido pero estan deshabilitadas.
4. Reinicia nuevamente, ingresa a la bios y  habilita el controlador de audio.
5. Guarda los cambios e inicia sesión en ubuntu.

Buala!!! el audio ya funciona!!!

Cualquier cosa comentas y te respondo, ya que antes de hacer esto primero tuve que reparar alsa pues el sistema de audio no mostraba ninguna tarjeta de sonido, ni siquiera "Salida para torpes".

Por si a alguno le pasa le recomiendo seguir [este post](http://www.ubuntu-es.org/node/186629#.Wop0G3VuZhH) y luego, cuando lleguen a la parte que dice "reparar pulse" seguir los pasos que aquí detallo.

Espero que les sea de ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: Excelente solución! Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Me funcionó con el primer comando. Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Si el audio de tu máquina ha funcionado correctamente, pero de repente te sale ese mensaje de "Salida para torpes", revisa si es que has tenido tu máquina demasiado tiempo sin reiniciar o apagar.

A mí me ha pasado que suelo tener mi máquina una semana o dos sin apagarla ni reiniciarla, solamente suspendiéndola; y en par de ocasiones ha aparecido ese problema, el cual he solucionado solamente con recargar el driver de Alsa:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Con eso, de inmediato ha regresado el audio. No ha hecho falta reiniciar ni cerrar nada de lo que he tenido en ejecución.

Answer (score 0):

Yo hice `rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*`¹ y luego usé `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service` y se arregló todo.

En si lo que estoy haciendo borrar toda configuración en *cache* (creo que se llama asi no estoy seguro ni soy experto) y reiniciar el servicio para que detecte todo nuevamente.

¹No existía la carpeta `~/.pulse` pero si hubiera existido yo habría ejecutado el comando `rm -r ~/.pulse/*`

Answer (score -1):

a mi me pasaba que no podia transmitir bien el audio a traves de hdmi, se escuchaba lento y distorsionado, instalé oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms.deb y solo me produjo mas problemas, esta vez, ya no mandaba nada de audio, lo desinstalé, y seguia con el problema original del audio lento, despues leyendo, encontré que el kernel (4.4.0) con el que viene mi ubuntu (16.04 lts) tenia algunos defectos, lo actualicé al 4.16 y se arregló el problema. Saludos

Comment: deberías revisar la solución que ya se dió, igual hasta a ti te sirve